# git-tf workflow best practice with few developers using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: git, xamarin.ios, git-tf

I work for a company developing an iOS app with Xamarin.  We chose Xamarin because we were already a C#, .NET, & TFS shop and it was easy to integrate TFS with the git-loving Xcode environment using git-tf.  But I'm still not sure what workflow is a best practice and has the least headaches.  I am especially looking for a workflow that is safe (i.e. I won't accidentally delete all my work with a rebase or what have you).

I've read git-tf's [Working With Teams](http://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Teams&referringTitle=Home) page, but it's not terribly helpful.

- Should I have a central git repo in addition to TFS?
- Should I work on a branch or my local master?
- Should I use --rebase when I pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's usually no need for a central git repository.  I've found that most users find that they want to use git-tf locally and be responsible for their own integration into TFS.
2. I would recommend using master to track TFS.  (In fact, `git-tf` enforces this at the moment.)  Work in a feature branch, then merge into your master branch and checkin to TFS.  What I do is:

   - Use `git-tf` to clone a TFS repository
   - Create a feature branch, let's call it `feature`, from master.
   - Do some work, committing into `feature` as needed.
   - Merge `feature` into `master`, and checkin to TFS.  Better:  rebase and squash into a single commit.
3. Probably.  Keeping your history linear is a good thing.  But if you use the workflow outlined in #2 above, you won't need to.